# Show that if $u(t)$ is a unit vector for all $t$ then $u(t)$ and $u'(t)$ are orthogonal for all $t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

Show that if $u(t)$ is a unit vector for all $t$ then $u(t)$ and $u'(t)$ are orthogonal for all $t$.

So if $u(t)$ is a unit vector it means that $u(t): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ right?

I'm not sure if it means that it is constant or not?

$u'(t)$ will also be a unit vector.

If it is constant then $u'(t) = 0$ so $u(t) \cdot u'(t) = 0$ and they are orthogonal but I'm not sure if this is correct or if I'm on the right track.

Comment: I think that you're confusing a constant length with a constant value.  For example, the vector $(sin(t),cos(t))$ has constant length (it is always 1), but it is not a constant vector.  Also $u(t)$ is not a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, it is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard question in multivariate calculus and solutions can be found in the common textbooks.

Suppose that $u(t)$ is a constant length vector.  Then, $\|u(t)\|$ is a constant function.  Therefor, $\|u(t)\|=c$ for some nonnegative real number $c$.  By squaring both sides, one has
$\|u(t)\|^2=c^2$.  $\|u(t)\|^2=u(t)\cdot u(t)$ where $\cdot$ is the dot product.  Therefore,
$$u(t)\cdot u(t)=c^2.$$
Now, take the derivative of both sides.  On the LHS, the product rule / power rule applies.  On the RHS, $c^2$ is a constant, so the derivative is $0$.  Therefore,
$$
u(t)\cdot u'(t)+u'(t)\cdot u(t)=0.
$$
Since the dot product is commutative, you have
$$
2u(t)\cdot u'(t)=0.
$$
By dividing by 2, 
$$
u(t)\cdot u'(t)=0.
$$
This is precisely the definition of the vectors being orthogonal.

Comment: but surely you need to take the norm of $u(t)$ ($||{u(t)}||$) and not simply just the absolute value

Comment: Wait. I think it's fine then because $||u|| = 1$ => $||u||^2=1$ => $u \cdot u = 1$ because the summation from $i=1,...,n$ of $x_i x_i = x \cdot x$

Comment: @StephanCasey I was being lazy, when I wrote $|u(t)|$, I mean the appropriate norm.

Answer (score 1):

$$\vec{u}(t)=(u_1(t),u_2(t),...,u_n(t))$$

$$\vec{u}'(t)=(u_1'(t),u_2'(t),...,u_n'(t))$$

$\vec{u}(t)$ is a unit vector means $u_1^2(t)+u_2^2(t)+...+u_n^2(t)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$0=(1)'=\langle u(t),u(t)\rangle'=\langle u'(t),u(t)\rangle+\langle u(t),u'(t)\rangle=2\langle u'(t),u(t)\rangle$ because we are in $\mathbb R$.