# $X$ is a vector field tangent to $S$ along $\alpha$, but always orthogonal to $\alpha$. Shouldn't $X \cdot \alpha = 0$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Part of the problem statement...

> Let $\alpha: I \rightarrow S$ be a unit speed curve in an n-surface, $S$, and let $X$ be a smooth vector field, tangent to $S$ along $\alpha$, which is everywhere orthogonal to $\alpha~$ ($\color{red}{(X(t)) \cdot \dot{\alpha(t)} = 0}$ for all $t \in I$).

This isn't the whole problem statement—but the part highlighted in red is what I'm questioning. If $X$ is orthogonal to $\alpha$ at all points, then shouldn't $X \cdot \alpha = 0$, and not $X \cdot \dot{\alpha} = 0$?

Comment: $X$ isn't orthogonal to $\alpha$, it says that $X$ is tangent to $\alpha$.  It is a calc III fact that the derivative of a unit speed curve is normal to the tangent.  See [Show that if u(t) is a unit vector for all t then u(t) and u′(t) are orthogonal for all t](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179443/show-that-if-ut-is-a-unit-vector-for-all-t-then-ut-and-ut-are-ort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting that $\alpha$ is a curve, not a vector field. However, $\dot{\alpha}(t)$ is a vector field along $\alpha$ (i.e., $\dot{\alpha}(t) \in T_{\alpha(t)}S$ for all $t \in I$), so it makes sense to require $X(t) \cdot \dot{\alpha}(t) = 0$.